# Two click differnets (Text and Image) and play audio

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have a text and a image that I add an attribute to each `onclick="playAudio()"`.

```
<h1 class="underline-on-hover" onclick="playAudio()" onmouseover="" cursor: pointer;">Test.</h1>
<img onclick="playAudio()" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" class="img-responsive" src="imagetest.png" alt="Image Test">
```

I want to do the following. If I click text playing audio, else if I click image stop playing audio at text and playing audio at image.
How to make that?

HTML audio.

```
<audio id="myAudio">
    <source src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

And JS.

```
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");
function playAudio() {
    x.play();
}
```

Comment: But there is only one audio. Do you mean to say that clicking on either text or image, the audio will play/pause alternatively?

Comment: Yes there is. I didn't mention. I mean, if I click text on Text playing audio but if I click on image, stop playing audio at text and playing audio at image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an overly simplistic code for that:

```
var audio1 = document.getElementById("audio1"),
  audio2 = document.getElementById("audio2"),
  whoIsPlaying = null;

function clickOnH1() {

  if (whoIsPlaying != 'H1') {

    audio2.pause();
    audio1.play();
    whoIsPlaying = 'H1';
  }
}

function clickOnIMG() {

  if (whoIsPlaying != 'IMG') {

    audio1.pause();
    audio2.play();
    whoIsPlaying = 'IMG';
  }
}
```

`clickOnH1` function should go into `onclick` attribute of H1 tag, and `clickOnIMG` function should go into `onclick` attribute of IMG tag.

Comment: Hello Blaze :).

Comment: Hi. Because I'm beginner yet, I have a question. Why do you put whoIsPlaying and in if (conditional statement) you have written (whoIsPlaying != 'H1' after you say whoIsPlaying ='H1'? Can you explain please me? :)

Comment: It helps to decide which audio to pause and which audio to play. If `H1` is currently playing then I stop audio1 and play audio2. And vice-versa for `IMG`

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you.

Comment: Blaze, I forgot a question. Why do you put Capital (H1, IMG)??

Comment: It's just a matter of preference

Answer (score 0):

Please find below snippet pass `this` as an argument so we can get `tagName` of clicked element and than put conditions accordingly..

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");
function playAudio(e) {
  if(e.tagName == "IMG")
    {
     alert('Stop') ; 
    }
  if(e.tagName == "H1")
    {
     alert('Play') ;
    }
  
}
```

```html
<h1 class="underline-on-hover" onclick="playAudio(this)" onmouseover="" cursor: pointer;">Test.</h1>
<img onclick="playAudio(this)" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" class="img-responsive" src="imagetest.png" alt="Image Test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple audio sources to tag doesn't work this way.

Something like this should work, if you only need to handle the image click right after text click.

```js
 var img = document.getElementById("img");
 function playAudio() {
  x = new Audio("sound.mp3");
  x.play();
    img.addEventListener('click',changeAudio(x));
 }
 function changeAudio(x){
  return function(){
   x.pause();
   x.src = "sound2.mp3";
   x.play();
  }
 }
```

```html
<h1 class="underline-on-hover" onclick="playAudio()" onmouseover="" cursor: pointer;">Test.</h1>
<img onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" id="img"
 class="img-responsive" src="imagetest.png" alt="Image Test">
```

Comment: I'm sorry if you mean there is only one audio. basically it's the same.